# Python GTK TreeView: Filter out non-matching search results, close childless nodes, color nodes differently

Tags: python, filter, model, treeview, gtk

[image: annotated example of my treeview][annotated example of my treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIovQ.png)

I am new to Python, GTK, and OO so I'm struggling to understand what documentation means (when there is documentation).  I have still managed to create the attached TreeView and use a filter plus use existing **GTK CTRL+F** functionality to type in text and hide rows.

Some questions (hopefully someone can point me to easy to understand (or commented) code that does any of the following

1. What is the terminology: **(a)** Arrow thingy to expand/contract **(b)** Tree node row **(c)** Tree data row?
2. I set up a filter with 'self.tree_filter.**set_visible_func**(self.filter_match_function)', I don't know how to tell data rows from tree nodes (I've hacked something that nearly works).
3. I would also like to **hide tree nodes that don't contain children**, but how do I tell they don't have children and I'm unsure about the order so it may have children (that get hidden later) when checked. Can I iterate over visible rows after "search" completes and tell if the arrow thingy is missing as a workaround?
4. I'd like to have **different colors** (or at least font, look) for tree nodes and data.
5. Ideally, I'd be able to click on the whole row and not just the tiny arrow thingy to expand/contract rows, if not I'll change it to change on hover which I know how to do.
6. I'd like to know how to iterate over the tree and do my own hiding/showing & contracting/expanding, I found this sample code which I unsuccessfully tried a lot of variations on:

   for x in range(1, len(model.get_path(iter))):
   niter = model.get_iter(model.get_path(iter)[:x])
   node = model.set_value(niter, COL_COLOR, "red")
   print model.get_path(iter)[:x], ":", model.get_value(niter, COL_COLOR)

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <--- Can't get code in pre (seen below) if I remove this or the badly formatted "code" above

```
for x in range(1, len(model.get_path(iter))):
    niter = model.get_iter(model.get_path(iter)[:x])
    node = model.set_value(niter, COL_COLOR, "red")
    print model.get_path(iter)[:x], ":", model.get_value(niter, COL_COLOR)
```